# DNN 6 User Level Module Permissions

Tags: dotnetnuke

When managing the settings of an HTML module in DNN 6 I'm able to add user usernames in the **permissions** tab below the user roles.

After doing so, I get a new row with 2 columns, Edit and View module.

If **Inherit View permissions from Page** is left unchecked, both the **View** and **Edit** module columns are locked.

If **Inherit View permissions from Page** is checked, **View** Module is locked, but **Edit** Module becomes accessible.

Why am I unable to edit view settings for individual users, and is there way to assign view privileges to a module on a user level?

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that this is a bug in DNN6 and would encourage you to look at upgrading to DNN7.

Also, I would advise against using User permissions. I would recommend you create a role, and assign that user to the role.

The problem with user level permissions is their inflexibility, for example: If the user ever leaves your organization, and you need to replace them with a new user, you have to go through and apply all the permissions over again. If you had used role based permissions, all you would need to do is remove User1 from the security role, and add the new User2 to the security role.

Comment: It does look like DNN7 actually precludes you from editing user based settings all-together  unless you inherit page permissions, in which case view is locked. DNN5 behaves the same as DNN6, it seems like user permissions were designed this way, but I can't fathom why.